# C# - How to transform a For loop into a Linq expression?

Tags: c#, linq, for-loop

I have the following loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < myStringList.Count; i++)
{
    myStringList[i] = myStringList[i].ToUpper();
}
```

into a Linq expression?

Comment: @h1ghfive: It does that for you??

Comment: @h1ghfive: I have ReSharper, but it didn't offer to.

Comment: I'm maybe wrong for a 'for' loop, but I am sure it does it for a 'foreach' loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
myStringList = myStringList.Select(x => x.ToUpper()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 5):

Use this

```
myStringList = myStringList.Select(x => x.ToUpper()).ToList();
```

I have used `.ToList()` in the end assuming that myStringList is a `List<string>`.

**FoodforThought:** In `List` there is a method `ForEach()` which performs an action on each item like this.

```
myStringList.ForEach(x => x.Foo = Bar);
```

But that cannot be used here as that method can be used to change a property of an item but cannot be used to change the item itself.

So this will not do anything

```
    myStringList.ForEach(x => x = x.ToUpper());
```

Comment: Yes, thank you as well. I will accept Darin Dimitrov's since he responded first, but +1. And, yes, I became aware that you can not change a list's items using ForEach when I first tried it, but thank you for the explanation nonetheless.